# What is the difference between CQL_FILTER and FILTER?

Tags: cql-filter, csw, cql

In a CSW request what is the difference between the parameters CQL_FILTER and FILTER ?

Examples:

```
localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw?REQUEST=GetRecords&CONSTRAINT_LANGUAGE_VERSION=1.1.0&RESULTTYPE=results&VERSION=2.0.2&TYPENAMES=gmd%3AMD_Metadata&CONSTRAINTLANGUAGE=CQL_TEXT&SERVICE=CSW&CONSTRAINT=Product
```

and

```
localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw?REQUEST=GetRecords&CONSTRAINT_LANGUAGE_VERSION=1.1.0&RESULTTYPE=results&VERSION=2.0.2&TYPENAMES=gmd%3AMD_Metadata&CONSTRAINTLANGUAGE=FILTER&SERVICE=CSW&CONSTRAINT=Product
```

Is there any CQL documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CQL (Common Query Language) is a query language created by the OGC for the [Catalogue Web Services specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/cat). Unlike the XML-based Filter Encoding language, CQL is written using a familiar text-based syntax. It is thus more readable and better-suited for manual authoring.

`Filter` is (usually) an [OGC filter](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/filter) which is expressed in XML and is more suited for machines to write.

Comment: It should also be noted that these parameters are optional and vendor specific, and can vary.

Comment: not in the CSW spec they aren't optional or vendor specific